# Long term data logging - Sampling every 20 ms for 24 hours

Tags: sqlite, logging

I am using max msp and the sql object described here :

https://cycling74.com/2008/09/05/data-collection-building-databases-using-sqlite/

I basically want to record an electrical voltage which I have streaming into max every 20 ms for 24 hours so I can play it back at various different speeds. Any idea how much space this is going to use up ? Id like to do this over 8 channels so 8 channels for 24 hours taking a sample every 20 ms - any tips appreciated.

Comment: You do not need to wait 24 hours for testing how much space is needed by 4320000 rows.

Comment: thanks I have already calculated the quantity of numbers that will be registered - but there may be metadata etc that I dont know about. What I would appreciate is a ballpark figure in megabytes  if possible ....

Comment: That depends on the contents of the rows. What prevents you from writing a test program?

Comment: Im completely new to SQL I want to know if what I want to do is feasable before learning the software. Thinking about it though it shouldn't be too big

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the table structure and on the contents of the rows.

With eight integers per row, like in this Python test script:

```py
import sqlite3
db=sqlite3.connect('logger.db')
c=db.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE log(ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4,ch5,ch6,ch7,ch8)')
for i in xrange(50*60*60*24):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO log VALUES(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)')
db.commit()
```

the database ends up at about 100 MB.